# Awk to sum all numbers only after a character string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I've a file with input as:

```
abc
def
ghi
23
54
12
tuy
12
iuy
56
67
```

I want to add all numbers after a character line and print it in front of character, like below:

```
abc
def
ghi 89
tuy 12
iuy 123
```

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold all the sums, then, in the END section, print them out, but suppress zero sums:

```
awk '/^[^0-9]/ {IX = $0} {SUM[IX] += $0} END {for (s in SUM) print s, SUM[s]?SUM[s]:""}' file
abc 
ghi 89
iuy 123
tuy 12
def
```

Be aware that the order in which an array's index is reproduced in e.g. `(s in SUM)` is undefined; if you need the output in the order of occurrence, additional (simple) measures need to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Print each alpha line without a newline at the end and then print the sum plus newline after adding up any numbers that followed it:

```
$ awk '
    /[[:alpha:]]/ { printf "%s%s%s%s", ofs, sum, ors, $0; sum=ofs=""; ors=ORS; next }
    { ofs=OFS; sum+=$0 }
    END { print ofs sum }
' file
abc
def
ghi 89
tuy 12
iuy 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{val=$0;next}$0~/^[0-9]*/{sum+=$0}/^[^0-9]/{print val,sum;val=$0;sum=0}END{print val,sum}' a.txt
abc 0
def 0
ghi 89
tuy 12
iuy 123
```

`NR==1{val=$0;next}` ---> when it reads the first line, keep the value in val variable and read the next line.

`$0~/^[0-9]*/{sum+=$0}` --> if its numeric then just sum it.

`/^[^0-9]/{print val,sum;val=$0;sum=0}` --> if it's not numeric, then just print the line and sum and reset the val and sum variables

Comment: thanks a lot everyone,can i mark more than one comment as solution?